# Spring cloud contract: using URL as response body parameter

Tags: java, groovy, spring-cloud-contract

In spring cloud contract (groovy) file I have issues with extracting a segment of request URL to use it as a parameter of in response body, e.g.

```
package contracts

import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    description "Should return OK "
    request {
        url "/discovery.svc/something(\'${value(consumer(regex(".*")),producer('defaultSomething'))}\')"
        method GET()
    }

    response {

        status 200
        body :
                value(
                        consumer(file("response/defaultSomething.xml").file.write(
                                String.format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                                        "<entry xmlns:metadata=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/metadata\" xmlns:data=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/data\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" metadata:context=\"http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/\$metadata#Environment/ContentServiceCapability\" xml:base=\"http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc\">\n" +
                                        "    <id>http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/something('%1\$s')</id>\n" +
                                        "    <title></title>\n" +
                                        "    <summary></summary>\n" +
                                        "    <updated>2020-03-23T15:19:53.272668900Z</updated>\n" +
                                        "    <author>\n" +
                                        "        <name>SDL OData v4 framework</name>\n" +
                                        "    </author>\n" +
                                        "    <link rel=\"edit\" title=\"ContentServiceCapability\" href=\"something('%1\$s')\"></link>\n" +
                                        "    <link rel=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/related/Environment\" type=\"application/atom+xml;type=entry\" title=\"Environment\" href=\"something('%1\$s')/Environment\"></link>\n" +
                                        "    <link rel=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/relatedlinks/Environment\" type=\"application/xml\" title=\"Environment\" href=\"something('%1\$s')/Environment/\$ref\"></link>\n" +
                                        "    <category scheme=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/scheme\" term=\"#Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.ContentServiceCapability\"></category>\n" +
                                        "    <content type=\"application/xml\">\n" +
                                        "        <metadata:properties>\n" +
                                        "            <data:id>%1\$s</data:id>\n" +
                                        "            <data:LastUpdateTime metadata:type=\"Int64\">1580489088713</data:LastUpdateTime>\n" +
                                        "            <data:URI>http://localhost:8081/content.svc</data:URI>\n" +
                                        "            <data:ExtensionProperties metadata:type=\"#Collection(Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.ContentKeyValuePair)\"></data:ExtensionProperties>\n" +
                                        "        </metadata:properties>\n" +
                                        "    </content>\n" +
                                        "</entry>", fromRequest().url().split('/')[-1].split('\'')[-2]))),
                        producer(file("response/defaultSomething.xml")))
        )
    }
}
```

the problen is that fromRequest().url() doesn't seem to be working and when I try to insert

```
print fromRequest().url()
```

in response section (in order to debug) I get as a result:

```
DslProperty{
clientValue={{{request.url}}},
        serverValue={{{request.url}}}}
```

instead of plain string URL. .toString() doesn't help neither. Do you have any ideas how can I get request.url as a plain string?

Comment: which version of contract are you using?I wonder if you're not the first person that uses XML and that code. I'm not sure if it works with XML :grimacing: Can you file an issue?

Comment: it is <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-tools</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0.RC2</version>
well, this XML is a response body that sevice returns and what I try to do is extracting segment of a url (fromRequest().url().split('/')[-1].split('\'')[-2])) ) and then paste this extracted segment into this body. For example endpoint looks like: /discovery.svc/something('userDefinedIndex'), entity itself has been pre-added to resource so service must return xml with all entries of 'userDefinedIndex' string changed to 'userDefinedIndex'

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak where should I file it?

Comment: Please file it here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues ; as a workaround you can just paste in a fixed response instead of referencing the request.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak thank you and here you go: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/1371